# How can I get proper week number in the start of the year

Tags: postgresql

I am currently involved in developing an app, where I need to sort incoming data, putting it in the tables depending on the year and the week of the incoming record.

### The problem

is that I am using `date_part('week', created_date)::text` to get the number of the week, it works just fine 99% of the time, but when the created_date is in the start of January, for example 02.01.2021, `date_part('week', created_date)::text` returning number 53, when logically it's obviously the first week of the year,
maybe you can suggest me how to get the proper week number for the 100% of the year?

Comment: Well it's not that obvious... 1st week of the year is usually the first week with a Thursday being in January.

Comment: you probably want ISO week **and** ISO year, e.g. `to_char(created_date, 'iyyy-iw')`. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Week#Week_numbering) for various ways to count the week numbers.

Comment: Did you mean 02.01.2021 instead of 02.01.2020? Because 02.01.2021 is week 53 2020 according to the ISO-8601 definition of week dates, while 02.01.2020 is week 1 2020 according to that same definition.

Comment: Maybe you should switch to using `isoyear` instead of `year`, so that values lineup.

Comment: I guess you meant "week" instead of "year" in your date_part() call, right?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel yes, I meant 02.01.2021, reading the comments i understood that there are many definitions of week dates, 
so if i use ISO week the code will return week number 1 of the 02.01.2021 or there is no way implementing that logic?

Comment: @mmmetafool No using `isoyear` will result in the returned year to make sense in combination with the value returned by `week`. BTW: I'm not aware of standards that would consider 02.01.2021 to be week 1 2021, so you may want to check your expectations

Comment: @S-Man yes, i will edit the question to get rid of misunderstandings in the future

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html):

> The number of the week of the year that the day is in. By definition
> (ISO 8601), the first week of a year contains January 4 of that year.
> (The ISO-8601 week starts on Monday.) In other words, the first
> Thursday of a year is in week 1 of that year.
>
> Because of this, it is possible for early January dates to be part of
> the 52nd or 53rd week of the previous year. For example, 2005-01-01 is
> part of the 53rd week of year 2004, and 2006-01-01 is part of the 52nd
> week of year 2005.

So, it's quite normal, that January 1st does not always lies in the first week. So, 53 is correct here because it means the 53rd week of the previous year.

---

Unfortunately there is nothing like `isoweek` for `date_part()` like there is `isoyear` for year. `week` is always the ISO week. But you can use this workaround:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=98cf321a0bfdf45bb6aa1678ae4b7031)

For converting a date into a string using a certain pattern, you can use `ww` and `iw` - week and ISO week:

```
SELECT to_char('2021-01-02'::date, 'iyyy-iw');
```

returns `2020-53`, the ISO values. Whereas

```
SELECT to_char('2021-01-02'::date, 'yyyy-ww');
```

returns `2021-01`, which is what you are expecting.

So you can use to_char to get your week number and than cast it into an `int`:

```
SELECT to_char('2021-01-02'::date, 'ww')::int;
```

Comment: Given the example it is not correct though, because 02.01.2020 is week 1 2020. Though likely the OP meant 2021 instead.

Comment: Extended the answer to show a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

53 is correct because it's the 53 week of 2019.

Checkout these links:

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html
- https://database.guide/get-the-week-number-from-a-date-in-postgresql/